# Opposite of dateutil.rrulestr()

Tags: python, icalendar, python-dateutil, rfc5545

The python-dateutil library provides the `rrule` class and the `rrulestr()` function which parses iCalendar recurrence rules into `rrule` instances.

Is there somewhere a function to serialize `rrule` instances into strings accepted by `rrulestr()`? There doesn't seem to be one in python-dateutil.